# Best practice format for RSS URL

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, rss

I'm setting up an RSS feed in ASP MVC and need to decide on the routing URL. Let's say the articles can be read at http://example.com/articles/ . Currently I have it routing to articles/rss but it could also be articles/rss.xml or articles.rss. Which of the following is most conventional:

- articles/rss
- articles.rss
- articles/rss.xml

or any other suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

To be perfectly clear: the URL does not matter very much. The right away of doing it is to make sure you add discovery in your HTML documents so that each doc points to the corresponding feed.
This is done by adding an `<link>` element inside the `<head>` of your HTML documents like this:

`<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Title of the Feed" href="http://url/to/your/feed">`

That being said, you should also try to use 'simple' urls for your feeds, mostly because users may need to copy and paste them. My favor goes to `/feed` but `/rss` works too :)